# HStack leading and trailing spacing in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, hstack

How can you add equal leading/trailing spacing to a scrollable HStack in SwiftUI? In this example there is spacing between the cells, but not in the first cell's leading or the last cell's trailing

I've tried adding `horizontal` spacing to the `ForEach` but that also spaces the cells, which is not what I want. I want equal spacing between the cells and the leading and trailing of the first and last cell in the loop

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(spacing: 5) {
                ForEach(0...1, id: \.self) {_ in
                    Capsule(style: .circular)
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add horizontal padding to the `HStack`

```swift
HStack(spacing: 5) {
  ForEach(0...1, id: \.self) {_ in
    // etc
  }
}
.padding(.horizontal, 5)
```

NB: `.horizontal` is a shortcut way of setting padding for both the leading and trailing edges at the same time – so `.padding([.leading, .trailing], 5)` is equivalent.

Comment: best to say `.padding()` and let iOS figure out the exact numbers.

Comment: @jjquirckart Maybe so, but the original question asked for “equal spacing between the cells and the leading and trailing of the first and last cell in the loop” so the answer took that part of the request into account!

Comment: Well, if you wanted to emphasize the horizontal padding, you could omit the length, i.e. `.padding(.horizontal)` to still allow the default amount of padding dependent on platform.